# How does Gibbs know so much about the Pelegostos?

Tags: pirates-of-the-caribbean, dead-mans-chest

In *Pirates of the Carribean: Dead Man's Chest*, after Will is put in the bone cages with the others, Gibbs tells him how the Pelegostos regard Jack as a god, and that when the drumming stops, the feast will begin and Jack will be eaten. This shows that Gibbs knows a lot about the Pelegostos, to the point where he understands how their feasting rituals work.

How does Joshamee Gibbs know so much about the Pelegostos?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Outside the movie, Mr. Gibbs serves as a [Mr. Exposition](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/MrExposition) trope. In all the movies he has "general pirate knowledge" and is quick to fill in the gaps for the audience. It is never explained how he comes across this tibbits, we are just left to assume he heard them from other pirates.

In this particular case, Gibbs was already there with Jack and the rest of the crew. We don't see the events unfolding, but clearly the crew and Jack know what is going to happen. Jack seems even able to converse with them at some level, so it's not hard to imagine any number of scenarios of how they come across this information. As the audience, we only see it from Will's perspective, so all we get is Gibbs exposition to catch us up.

Comment: You may want to edit your answer with information from [this one](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/91501/63559): Gibbs likely knew this religion already, because Jack had already dealt with the Pelegostos.

Answer (score 0):

We see in the first movie when jack is talking to dumb and dumber when Elizabeth falls off the cliff from not being able to breathe that jack was in the middle of telling them “and then they made me their chief…” possibly foreshadowing this sub plot in the second movie. Also we know that Gibbs and jack have much history so Gibbs most likely knew this as well and now has been reintroduced to the pelegostos tribe.